# Split data import to google sheets from mysql

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to split the data push from a mysql table to google sheets.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  while (result.next()) {
    var rowData = [];
    for (var column = 0; column < result.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); column++) {
      rowData.push(result.getString(column + 1));
    }
    data.push(rowData);
  }
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Is there a way I could break the push at 2500 records and have the trigger pick it up at 2501 and break at 5000 and so on until all the table data is pushed to sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Use the properties service (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) to store your iteration count then have the script reference it when running from the trigger.

Properties are stored as strings so remember to convert to number to perform calculations.

```
//On script exit write the iteration count
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
scriptProperties.setProperty('myCount', i);

//when the script runs get the latest iteration count, and start at next
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var startNUmber = scriptProperties.getProperty('myCount').parseInt() + 1;
```